# How to mock a function in a component in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have not done any jest or testing in a long time and I'm struggling with this test. I have this button component where the value of disabled attribute comes from the redux store.
When user logs in I am making a call to backend and saving some data in the redux store and then while browsing if a user gets to this particular page. I am reading the data from the store, modifying it to create an object then that is what is passed to the buttons.

My component has these two material-ui buttons.

```
<Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={!permissions.admin|| !permissions.moderator} id="btn-reports">Reports</Button>
<Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={!permissions.admin|| !permissions.moderator} id="btn-charts">Charts</Button>
```

Parent Component generates the value of permissions object from a helper function getPermissions (below) reading state directly from the store.

```
const getPermissions = () => {
  const permissions = store.getState().permisisons;
  const accessToButtons = {
    admin: false,
    moderator: false
  }

  for(const permission of permissions) {
    if (permission.admin === true) {
     accessButtons.admin = true;
    } else if (permission.moderator === true) {
     accessButtons.moderator= true;
    }
  }

  return accessToButtons;

}
```

Right now I am getting an error when I run jest because the button is disabled. I believe it has the default value of false and I am trying to write a test to check onclick which fails. I have a helper function for handleDisabled where I am iterating over an object in the store and based on that button is disabled. Can someone guide me what I need to do here. How do I mock the function by providing some mock values for that object so I have control over disabling/enabling those buttons.
I have been playing around with `jest.fn` and `jest.spyOn` but I've had no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: So I have solved this by adding jest.spyOn(newlyCreatedObjectWithGetPermissions, getPermissions).mockReturnValue(mockPermissonsObject) and then ofcourse permissonsObject has {admin: true, moderator: false}. Is this the right way?

Comment: I'd say with RTL the more you can interact with the component being tested the way the app/UI code and user would the better. I don't think you should get the state directly from the store like you have in `getPermissions`, but you would normally have a component "subscribe" to the redux context being provided to the app... simply create a mock redux provider wrapper for the component being tested. If you happen to still use the `connect` HOC then export and test the unconnected component and just mock the props that would be mapped from redux.